# Absolute URI won't work

Tags: prism

Visual Studio 2017, Latest Xamarin.Forms, Latest Prism.

No matter what I try, I can't get my absolute URI to work.  I have my app launch from app.xaml to a login page.  In the loginpageviewmodel, I do some checks to see if the user is authenticated and if so, then I want to navigate to the mainpage.

I can navigate to the mainpage when not using absolute uri and it works - but the back button goes back to the login page - not wanted.

Code:

```
if (user.isAuthenticated)
{
navigationService.NavigateAsync("/AppMasterDetailPage/NavigationPage/MainPage"));
}
```

I've added all the http:// and the myapp.com, etc. ... nothing I try works.

How do I change the uri so absolute will navigate to proper main page and disallow the back button to the login page?

Comment: Can you replicate the issue in a sample you can share? Absolute Navigation is equivalent to `App.MainPage = new MainPage()` so if you are using absolute navigation there wouldn't be anything to go back to except the home screen of your device.

Comment: I think you are missing the question.  Application starts and launches the login page.  But before the page actually shows, I check to see if stored credentials are still valid.  If they, I want to bypass the login altogether and just navigate to the "real" main page of the app.  That page is a master detail page with hamburger menu, detail pages, etc.  No matter what I try from all the other posts about absolute uri, I can't bypass the login screen without the user being able to hit the back button and viewing the login page.  And why is that a -1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out the following [sample project](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Forms/tree/master/HamburgerMenu) which uses a "Login Screen" and a Hamburger Menu.

I haven't tested an attempted Navigation from `OnNavigatingTo`, but I wouldn't expect that to work properly as the page hasn't actually been pushed to the stack yet. That said if you did your check to see if the user is authenticated in `OnNavigatedTo` you could perform the navigation without a problem. If you do not want your user to see the LoginPage then the best I could tell you would be to have a SplashScreen that you first navigate to, and then do your logic from there to decide whether to go to your LoginPage or MasterDetailPage

Comment: Never thought about the OnNavigatingTo ... don't want to see the login page at all unless necessary.  I will try to move the authentication check to the MainPage first and then navigate to LoginPage if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution ...

I have app.xaml navigate to the loginpage.  In the OnNavigatedTo method, I check for user authentication.  If authenticated, then I call

```
NavigatgeAsync("/masterpage/navpage/mainpage");
```

and this gets me to the proper mainpage of the app and the back button DOES NOT go back to the login page - it exits app like expected.  So the "/masterpage..." is the absolute uri I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Next time you should do this instead `_navigationService.NavigateAsync( new Uri("http://www.xxxx.com/Index/Navigation/Home", UriKind.Absolute));` this is after you have authenticated and have injected the `NavigationService`.